# simple_form radio button (need to add <span> tag inside of <label>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

What is the best way to create the following HTML using simple_form_for gem?

```
<label>
   <input name="form-field-radio" type="radio" />
   **<span class="lbl"> radio option 2</span>**
</label>
```

Note that by default when I create a radio buttons using the following statements, the  above is not created.  How can I add that  tag in?

```
<%= f.input :state, :collection => Project::STATES, :as => :radio_buttons %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need (to embed a `<span>` within the `<label>`).  It isn't the cleanest solution but it did work and I think with some tweaking it could get you the ability to have your input and span embedded within the label.  The following modification results in:

```
<label>Name: 
  <span class="hint">this is a hint...</span>
</label>
```

I added the following as an initializer (using rails 4 and simple_form 3) to override the label_text method:

```
# initializers/simple_form_custom.rb
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Labels

      def label_text
        if hint
          hint_text = %[<span class="hint">#{hint}</span>]
        else
          hint_text = ""
        end
        SimpleForm.label_text.call(raw_label_text, required_label_text, hint_text).strip.html_safe
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Then in `initializers/simple_form.rb` I have:

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, hint| "#{label}: #{required} #{hint}" }
```